How can I plot UMAP plots in plotly.js?
Everything online I found for plotly.js is using plotly python which doesn't help me too much since I need it in JS, python also seems to use additional libraries. I created a function that plots it
export const RenderUmapPlotsData = (csv, runid, camera) => {
    try {
        const getPlotColor = index => {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    return '#FF4500'; // OrangeRed
                case 1:
                    return '#32CD32'; // LimeGreen
                case 2:
                    return '#1E90FF'; // DodgerBlue
                case 3:
                    return '#FFD700'; // Gold
                case 4:
                    return '#4B0082'; // Indigo
                case 5:
                    return '#FF1493'; // DeepPink
                case 6:
                    return '#00CED1'; // DarkTurquoise
                case 7:
                    return '#FF6347'; // Tomato
                case 8:
                    return '#ADFF2F'; // GreenYellow
                case 9:
                    return '#8A2BE2'; // BlueViolet
                case 10:
                    return '#00FF7F'; // SpringGreen
                case 11:
                    return '#8B0000'; // DarkRed
                case 12:
                    return '#B8860B'; // DarkGoldenRod
                case 13:
                    return '#4682B4'; // SteelBlue
                case 14:
                    return '#D2691E'; // Chocolate
                case 15:
                    return '#DA70D6'; // Orchid
                case 16:
                    return '#5F9EA0'; // CadetBlue
                case 17:
                    return '#7FFF00'; // Chartreuse
                case 18:
                    return '#DC143C'; // Crimson
                case 19:
                    return '#FF8C00'; // DarkOrange
                case 20:
                    return '#9932CC'; // DarkOrchid
                case 21:
                    return '#00BFFF'; // DeepSkyBlue
                case 22:
                    return '#228B22'; // ForestGreen
                case 23:
                    return '#FF00FF'; // Fuchsia
                default:
                    return '#000000'; // Black
            }
        };

        const getRunIdByCamera = (runid) => {
            return runid?.split('_')[0] || runid
        }

        const y = csv.map(item => item.y);
        const barcodes = csv.map(item => item.barcode)
    
        const X_umap_0 = csv.flatMap(item => item.X_umap_0);
        const X_umap_1 = csv.flatMap(item => item.X_umap_1);
        
        const xMin = [
            Math.min(...X_umap_0),
            Math.min(...X_umap_1)
        ];
        
        const xMax = [
            Math.max(...X_umap_0),
            Math.max(...X_umap_1)
        ];
        
        const X = csv.map(item => [
            item.X_umap_0.map(val => (val - xMin[0]) / (xMax[0] - xMin[0])),
            item.X_umap_1.map(val => (val - xMin[1]) / (xMax[1] - xMin[1]))
        ]);

        const uniqueY = Array.from(new Set(y));

    
        const data = uniqueY.map((j, idx) => {
            const existingBarcodeName = barcodes.find((_, i) => y[i] === j);
            const name = existingBarcodeName ? existingBarcodeName : j === -1 ? 'unidentified barcode / failed quality RSQ' : j.toString();

            const trace = {
                x: [],
                y: [],
                mode: 'markers',
                marker: {
                    color: idx === -1 ? 'black' : getPlotColor(idx),
                    size: 6,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                },
                name: idx === -1 ? 'unidentified barcode / failed quality RSQ' : name,
                type: 'scatter',
            };
            X.forEach((item, index) => {
                if (y[index] === j) {
                    trace.x.push(item[0][0]);
                    trace.y.push(item[1][0]);
                }
            });
            return trace;
        });

        const layout = {
            title: `UMAP Projection ${getRunIdByCamera(runid)} ${camera}`,
            xaxis: {
                visible: true,
            },
            yaxis: {
                visible: true,
            },
            legend: {
                x: 1.1,
                y: 1,
                font: {
                    size: 15,
                },
            },
        };

        const dataUmap = data;
        const config = {
            modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['sendDataToCloud', 'displaylogo', 'pan2d', 'pan3d', 'autoScale2d', 'resetScale2d'],
            displaylogo: false,
            displayModeBar: true
        };
        return { data: dataUmap, layout: layout, config: config };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        return undefined;
    }
}

I spoke to the Algorithms Developer that assigned me the ticket and he sent me this code block in python that is the logic to plot it
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_Umap(df_Umap, df_existing_barcodes=None, runID=""):

    X = np.stack([df_Umap["X_umap_0"], df_Umap["X_umap_1"]], axis=1)
    y = df_Umap["Y"]
    x_min, x_max = np.min(X, 0), np.max(X, 0)
    X = (X - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("tab20b", len(np.unique(y)))
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    for idx, j in enumerate(np.unique(y)):

        if (df_existing_barcodes is not None) & np.any(df_existing_barcodes.values == j):
            barcode_name = df_existing_barcodes[(df_existing_barcodes.values == j)].index[0]
        else:
            barcode_name = str(j)

        if j == -1:
            plt.plot(
                X[(y == -1), 0],
                X[(y == -1), 1],
                ".",
                color="black",
                markersize=2,
                label="unidentified barcode \n / failed quality RSQ",
            )
        else:
            plt.plot(X[(y == j), 0], X[(y == j), 1], ".", color=cmap(idx), markersize=2, label=" " + barcode_name)

    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    title = set_title("UMAP", runID)
    plt.title(title, fontsize=20)
    plt.legend(fontsize=15, markerscale=5, bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1), loc="upper left")

So with my RenderUmapPlotsData(), it's the converted python code. But I got a single scatter point for each key, I was expecting multiple per key. I don't use python so I am not sure if I accurately converted the logic or if the matplotlib.pyplot python library plots it differently from plotly.js.
Data structure I'm sending to the plot is
data:  [
{
"barcode": "TT",
"y": 1018,
"X_umap_0": [5.633621096611023, 5.426720380783081, 5.546037912368774, 5.689118146896362, ...],
"X_umap_1": [ 4.7906142473220825, 4.880273103713989, 4.7140690088272095, 5.0658169984817505, ...],
},
{
"barcode": "Z0115",
"y": 940,
"X_umap_0": [0.8259536474943161, 0.72834712266922, 1.5240634679794312, 0.7071684952825308, ...],
"X_umap_1": [3.501920700073242, 4.718092381954193, 2.6759512424468994, 3.722422480583191, ...],
},
]
Data structure being sent to pythons plot_Umap is

Output I got:

Output I was expecting:

